# Pull specific values from one dataframe based on values in another

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I have two dataframes

df1:

| Country | value | Average | Week Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UK | 42 | 42 | 1 |
| US | 9 | 9.5 | 2 |
| DE | 10 | 9.5 | 3 |
| NL | 15 | 15.5 | 4 |
| ESP | 16 | 15.5 | 5 |
| POL | 17 | 18 | 6 |
| CY | 18 | 18 | 7 |
| IT | 20 | 18 | 8 |
| AU | 17 | 18 | 9 |
| FI | 18 | 18 | 10 |
| SW | 20 | 18 | 11 |

df2:

| Country | value | Average | Year Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US | 42 | 42 | 1 |
| UK | 9 | 9.5 | 2 |
| ESP | 10 | 9.5 | 3 |
| SW | 15 | 15.5 | 4 |
| IT | 16 | 15.5 | 5 |
| POL | 17 | 18 | 6 |
| NO | 18 | 18 | 7 |
| SL | 20 | 18 | 8 |
| PO | 17 | 18 | 9 |
| FI | 18 | 18 | 10 |
| NL | 20 | 18 | 11 |
| DE | 17 | 18 | 12 |
| AU | 18 | 18 | 13 |
| CY | 20 | 18 | 14 |

Im looking to create a column in df1 that shows the 'Year Rank' of the countries in df1 so that I have the following:

| Country | value | Average | Week Rank | Year Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UK | 42 | 42 | 1 | 2 |
| US | 9 | 9.5 | 2 | 1 |
| DE | 10 | 9.5 | 3 | 9 |
| NL | 15 | 15.5 | 4 | 8 |
| ESP | 16 | 15.5 | 5 | 3 |
| POL | 17 | 18 | 6 | 6 |
| CY | 18 | 18 | 7 | 7 |
| IT | 20 | 18 | 8 | 5 |
| AU | 17 | 18 | 9 | 13 |
| FI | 18 | 18 | 10 | 10 |
| SW | 20 | 18 | 11 | 4 |

How would i loop through the countries in df1 and find the corresponding rank in df2?

Edit: I am only looking for the yearly rank of the countries in df1

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df1['Year Rank'] = df1.merge(df2, on='Country')['Year Rank']
```

Comment: thanks but im only looking for the top 10 from df1 and their yearly rank isnt always in the top 10

Comment: @flaws49 Then modify your question accordingly. I answered your original question of how to loop through the countries in df1 and find the corresponding rank in df2. Either give us more data or change your question, otherwise it's impossible to answer your question.